# Button click to remove all ticks using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```html
<label> <input type="checkbox" class="check">hello</label>
<label> <input type="checkbox" class="check">world</label><br>
<input type="submit" class="clear" value="Clear"/>
```

Two checkbox here 
1)click the two checkbox first 
2)After clear button click to remove ticks using jquery

Comment: `$(input[type="submit"]).on('click', function(){ $('.check').prop('checked', false); })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');`  by using this you can remove the selected checkboxes

```js
$('.clear').on('click',function(){
$('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label> <input type="checkbox" class="check">hello</label>
<label> <input type="checkbox" class="check">world</label><br>
<input type="submit" class="clear" value="Clear"/>
```

Comment: If it is working give upvote to the answers and mark it as a correct answer. so that Others will get benifited from this answer

Comment: OP must use `prop` over `removeAttr` as setting the `boolean` value to change the property makes more sense than `removing` and `adding` attribute. Refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr).

Answer (score 2):

```js
   $(document).on('click', 'input[type="submit"]', function(){ 
      $('.check').prop('checked', false);
   })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label> <input type="checkbox" class="check">hello</label>
<label> <input type="checkbox" class="check">world</label><br>
<input type="submit" class="clear" value="Clear"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay.

Answer (score 1):

You need to prevent the default action of `submit` button otherwise `action` over `form` will take place.

Use `prop()` method to set the `checked` property to `false`

```js
$('.clear').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.check').prop('checked', false);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="check">hello</label>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="check">world</label>
<br>
<input type="submit" class="clear" value="Clear" />
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.clear').on('click', function(){ 
      $('.check').prop('checked', false);
   })
});

<script>
```

if you have any trouble on this post the error you got on console.